# AngularJS Style Guide: String literals when accessing modules

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In [John Papa's style guide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide#style-y001), and I have seen this in multiple other places as well, the recommended way of accessing modules is with the getter syntax like so...

```
angular
    .module('app')
    .controller('SomeController', SomeController);
```

But why would I want to use a string literal for my app name? String literals, aka magic strings, are rarely a good idea so it's puzzling to me why I would want to do this in every angular file of my application.

Why wouldn't this be better?

```
//declared globally with name spacing but abbreviated for this example
var appName = "app";

angular
    .module(appName)
    .controller('SomeController', SomeController);
```

Comment: Why do you think that a global identifier `appName` would be better than a global module name `app`?

Comment: it is a good practice to avoid global variables in JavaScript

Comment: One is a string literal and if I change the name of my app I now need to update more than likely a large number of files. The alternate is a variable that I only update in one place.